# How to pass an array data from iphone to apple watch in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

i have to develop an apple watch application in which i have to show some tabular view in the apple watch . For this operation i have already Core data in my iPhone from which i get retrieved in to a NSArray object. 
But now i want to pass it to the watch kit extension so how its possible?
is any one have idea ?

Below is the function which returns the Core date fetched records in the form of array objects.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getWatchHomeView
{

NSMutableArray *resultTracks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.ongoingMapArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[self fetchResultsForCompletedExpeditions:NO] fetchedObjects]];
NSLog(@"ongoingMapArray-- %lu",(unsigned long)[self.ongoingMapArray count]);
self.completedMapArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[self fetchResultsForCompletedExpeditions:YES] fetchedObjects]];
NSLog(@"completedMapArray-- %lu",(unsigned long)[self.completedMapArray count]);

for (int i=0; i < self.completedMapArray.count; i++)
{
    WatchTable *watchTableRow = [[WatchTable alloc] init];
    Map *mapObject = [self.completedMapArray objectAtIndex:i];

    watchTableRow.trackName = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [mapObject name]] uppercaseString];
    NSArray *arrPolylines = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[self fetchPloylineForMaps:[mapObject name]] fetchedObjects]];

    if ([arrPolylines count] > 0) {
        double totalDis = [self getTotalDistanceFromPolylines:arrPolylines];
        watchTableRow.trackedDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km", totalDis];


        Polyline *firstPolyline = [arrPolylines lastObject];
        NSMutableArray *arrTimeData = (NSMutableArray*)firstPolyline.time;
        if ([arrTimeData count] > 0) {
            watchTableRow.trackedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ago", [self getPausedTimeWithCreationDate:[arrTimeData lastObject]]];
        }else{
            watchTableRow.trackedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ago", [self getPausedTimeWithCreationDate:firstPolyline.creationDate]];
        }
    }else{
        watchTableRow.trackedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ago", [self getPausedTimeWithCreationDate:mapObject.creationDate]];
        watchTableRow.trackedDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.00 Km"];
    }
    NSLog(@"watchTableRow = %@",watchTableRow);
    [resultTracks addObject:watchTableRow];

}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:resultTracks forKey:@"WatchHomeViewTableList"];

return resultTracks;
}
```

Comment: Which watchOS do you use? (OS1 or OS2). Do you know WatchConnectivity?

Comment: its OS1, and i'm trying to pass this array object using openParentApplication method by wrapping the array object into dictionary but every time its giving me null in reply

Comment: yes, somewhere i red about watch connectivity, its good and works on OS2 but if i have to use OS1 so is it possible ?

Comment: WatchConnectivity doesn't work on OS 1. I added answer. Good luck!

Comment: @KosukeOgawa - can you please suggest on my below query ? commented on your answer

Comment: Do you want to restore data on the watch side? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use watchOS 1, you can share data between your watch and iOS App with App Groups.

ref.

- [Share Data in your Swift WatchKit Apps with App Groups](http://www.codingexplorer.com/share-data-in-your-swift-watchkit-apps-with-app-groups/)
- [WATCHKIT: BEST PRACTICES FOR SHARING DATA BETWEEN YOUR WATCH AND IOS APP](http://www.kristinathai.com/watchkit-best-practices-for-sharing-data-between-your-watch-and-ios-app/)

**EDIT:**

On the iphone side, serialize your data.

```
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:resultTracks];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
    initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.example.mygroup"];
[defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:@"WatchHomeViewTableList"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And unserialize your data.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
    initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.example.mygroup"];
NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"WatchHomeViewTableList"];
NSMutableArray *resultTracks = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your valuable Documents and i have red it and implemented the same. i got the reason why my reply object was null and showing the message "Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 " because of i was using my custom class object assigning it to NSArray which was failing to pass in reply. But now i have serialise my custom class object before adding it to NSArray object still the problem is that how i can restore this object in to extension side sine that custom class belongs to iPhone app context side as you mentioned in your watch side code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to exchange data from your iPhone app to Apple Watch app under watchOS 1.0 with App Groups:

- **NSUserDefaults with suite:** you can use NSUserDefaults with a virtual "box" of data that is shared between your app and the extension. Simply create a new NSUserDefaults instance with the method `-[NSUserDefaults initWithSuiteName:@"myAppGroupIdentifier"]` and use it like the shared user defaults provided by iOS. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/
- **Darwin notifications:** a low-level implementation of the *observer* pattern, like the one used in NSNotificationCenter. This is a little bit difficult to use, so I recommend to use MMWormhole instead. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html
- **MMWormhole:** a wrapper for Darwin notifications, but with a simple communication model similar to the one used in WKInterfaceController/AppDelegate. You can find this library on GitHub.

Please note that you first need to register an App Group Identifier into your Apple Developer account.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html) for updates about watchOS 2.0 and 3.0.